# Windows phone emaultors will not run

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

Has anyone ever had a problem like the attached error message when trying to run the windows phone emulators in VS?

*** The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to ensure the virtual machine was running. Something happened while starting a virtual machine: 'Emulator 8.0 Update 3 720P.jason' failed to start. (Virtual Machine ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) not actually XXX's just not typing out the ID.

'Emulator 8.0 720P.jason' failed to start work process: This version of the emulator 8.0 update 3 720P.jason is not compatible with the version of windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher. (0x800700D8) Virtual Machine ID XXXXXX

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro 64Bit. I did just upgrade from non-pro to pro.  I have ensured my processor and BIOS support and have enabled virtualization. I have ensured Hyper-V is installed.

I have searched for a couple of days and have tried some small suggestions, but nothing seems to work. I have tried to manually start the virtual machine, but it still tells me that my version of windows is incorrect.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this can helps but... take a look at your user to ensure it is member of HyperV Administrators. Sometimes SDK can't make the change, and you need it to be member of that group.

Comment: I guess de- and re-activating hyper-v, removing the virtual machines in Hyper V and maybe also reinstalled VS could help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a problem with all of the different version of visual studio that I had installed along with the sdk's that came with them. IE: RC1, etc. I also had a problem where the emulators didnt' recognize I was running 64 bit windows when I really was. I actually posted a blog about it where I ended up doing a reinstall to correct the problem.

http://thebrockside.blogspot.com/2014/02/windows-phone-emulators-failing-to.html